# MVC 4 ajax get param with "/"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im calling a controller method that accepts 2 parameters with jquery ajax get.

One of my parameter has "/" and is recognized as 2 parameters.

I use encodeURIComponent on that parameter but still the ajax call throws an Not found error?

here is my ajax code for calling my controller:

```
var param1 = 'value1',
    param2 = 'value/2';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: HostPath + "api/ratings/" + param1 + '/' + encodeURIComponent(param2),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //success
        }
    });
```

Here is my Controller action

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/ratings/{param1}/{param2}")]
    public IList<Ratings> GetRating(string param1, string param2)
    {
        // logic
        return _result;
    }
```

Comment: What is the generated URL? Did you tried sending data using data attribute of $.ajax method?